# socialManager.isFollowed(socialActor) only returning 0 or false, but never true

Tags: javascript, social

Any ideas why I'm only getting 0 or false, but never true for result.get_value()?

```
// Set IsFollowed correctly.
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var socialManager = new SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);
var socialActor = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();
socialActor.set_contentUri(url);
socialActor.set_actorType(SP.Social.SocialActorType.site);
result = socialManager.isFollowed(socialActor);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        if (result.get_value())
        {
            this.IsFollowed = ko.observable(true);
        }
        else
        {
            this.IsFollowed = ko.observable(false);
        }
        //alert("IsFollowed = " + this.IsFollowed);
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        // Failed.
        alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```

I am doing the above when pushing to an observablearray in knockout.js, and wait for the social manager to load:

```
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        // Make sure SocialFollowingManager is available
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager',             
        function () {
            //ko.applyBindings(new LinksViewModel(), document.getElementById("springim-core-menu-list-links"));
            ko.applyBindings(new MyQuickLinksViewModel(), document.getElementById("springim-myquicklinks"));
            ko.applyBindings(new MyFollowedSitesViewModel(), document.getElementById("springim-core-menu-list-followedsites"));
        });
    });
```

Oddily enough, I use the same code elsewhere when the page has loaded on a click event and it reads the value correctly (just true/false).

Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

May be you are getting random results because the "result" variable is a global variabile. Try to put a "var" before it to make it local
`var result = socialManager.isFollowed(socialActor);`